# What is better: I can tell or I tell..?

Tags: word-usage

I tell a bad car from a good one by..  is this correct or should I use.. I can tell a good car from a bad one by..  I am confused because I always hear the second option but someone told me the first one is also correct.

Comment: They are both fine. There is a subtle difference I'm having trouble articulating, but it's small enough that you can ignore it. The second form, *can tell*, is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct, as long as you have the "by....".  Of the two, "I can tell.." is probably more common. "I tell..." means that is the way you decide, whereas  "I can tell..." allows the possibility there might be other ways to tell, as well.  Note that in either construction you could substitute *distinguish* for *tell*.

However, if you **didn't** have the "by..." clause:

- I tell a good car from a bad one. (incorrect)
- I can tell a good car from a bad one. (correct)

Comment: That raises another question, what do you think of this example:  How does a mom tell her kids are lying?

Comment: I would add a _that_ after "tell". This avoids the initial mis-parsing "tell her kids" as telling _them_ something.

Answer (score -1):

Both options are correct, with a subtle difference as mentioned in the comment. "I **tell** a bad car from a good one..." implies that you are currently, at that very moment, evaluating the car and deciding whether or not it is good or bad. On the other hand, "I **can** tell a bad car from a good one..." conveys that you have the ability to do so, but that you aren't currently doing it.  The first option can also be rewritten (and most commonly is) as "I **am telling** a bad car apart from a good one".